# How to store inserted time automatically in mongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to automatically save the time of insertion into mongodb as `'created_on' : new Date(),` below is JSON object but running into an error, is there a way this can be done?please provide guidance

```
data = {
    "orgRadar" : 36353275,
    'created_on' : new Date(),
    "clonedRadars" : [ 
        {
            "clonedRadar" : 39851508,
            "clonedStatus" : "PASS",
            "clonedStatusfailReason" : "N/A",
            "updateStatus" : "PASS",
            "updatedFailedReason" : "N/A"
        }, 
        {
            "clonedRadar" : 39394842,
            "clonedStatus" : "PASS",
            "clonedStatusfailReason" : "N/A",
            "updateStatus" : "FAIL",
            "updatedFailedReason" : "Category Required"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error:

```
  File "mongodb_insertdata.py", line 39
    'created_on' : new Date(),
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you included the whole stack trace and the rest of your Python code... note that `new Date()` looks like JavaScript. If you're using Python, you should use something like `import datetime` and then `"created_on": datetime.datetime.utcnow()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're writing in Python given the tag and little bit of stack trace you copied. `new Date()` isn't going to work in Python, since that's JavaScript:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> new Date()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    new Date()
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

You should probably use something like:

```
import datetime

data = {
    "orgRadar" : 36353275,
    "created_on" : datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    "clonedRadars" : [ 
        {
            "clonedRadar" : 39851508,
            "clonedStatus" : "PASS",
            "clonedStatusfailReason" : "N/A",
            "updateStatus" : "PASS",
            "updatedFailedReason" : "N/A"
        }, 
        {
            "clonedRadar" : 39394842,
            "clonedStatus" : "PASS",
            "clonedStatusfailReason" : "N/A",
            "updateStatus" : "FAIL",
            "updatedFailedReason" : "Category Required"
        }
    ]
}
```

If using Python, you should refer to the PyMongo documentation instead of the MongoDB documentation, since those will match your language bindings. PyMongo datetime examples and information can be found [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/datetimes.html?highlight=datetime).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `$currentDate`, since it corresponds to your type which is `Date`.

You can read more from the documentation here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/